# Custom PHP tagging system assistance, finding username

Tags: php, html, tags, system

I am currently making a tag system within my profile page of my website. If the user specifies: `+tag[username]` where username is equal to a username that the person is friends with, it will preg_replace the tag with a link to the user. Finding the +tag using strpos is easy, but the question i am asking is how to pull the username as a variable. e.g: if $text = 'hey +tag[matty] how are you!'

```
if (strpos($text, '+tag[//username//]' !== false)) {
//get //username// and store as $username
}
```

so that it would look like this:

```
if (strpos($text '+tag[//username//]' !== false) {
   $username = "matty";
}
```

thankyou to all who reply in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the regular expression matching function [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)?

```
$subject = "hey +tag[matty] how are you!";
$pattern = '/\+tag\[(.*?)\]/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
$username = $matches[1];
echo $username;
```

To match multiple instances of the tag, you'd want to use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$subject = "Hey +tag[matty]! Want to meet up with +tag[keshia] later?";
$pattern = '/\+tag\[(.*?)\]/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $username){
    echo $username.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: hey there glen, thanks for the quick reply, in terms of this what does PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE do? thanks once more

Comment: From php.net: `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE
If this flag is passed, for every occurring match the appendant string offset will also be returned. Note that this changes the value of matches into an array where every element is an array consisting of the matched string at offset 0 and its string offset into subject at offset 1.`

Comment: For your use case it probably isn't necessary actually. I've revised my code to not use the flag. If you're curious, it grabs the string offset of the match.

Comment: I have another slight question to ask if thats ok. How could you use this code to detect multiple occurrences of +tag[//username] and store them in an array? All help is appreciated thanks. So far i have counted the occurrences with '$amount = substr_count($content, '+tag[');'.